# I want to remove Skype chat history from Outlook.com

Tags: outlook.com, skype-for-web

Please note, I'm not talking about the Skype chat history on the Skype software, which I can easly delete by going to Tools/Options/Privacy, etc...

I'm talking about that all of my chat conversations I do on Skype using the normal Skype software are also being saved on the cloud!

I'm using a Microsoft account to login to Skype since this is an old account I have with lots of contacts that I used to have since the Messenger, so I keep using that.

Yes, even I have no history on Skype, if I log into my account I can see all my previous chat history since the begining of the time, I've gone back a couple of months browsing and it seems everything is there, all my conversations with all my contacts are on the web, despite I explicitly told Skype to not keep history (and it obeys, but just for the desktop).

I have searched and wasted hours on Google trying to find and only could find a single thread with the same complaint I have now. Most of the articles I found are garbage related to the normal procedure for deleting the history.

I also found articles where they say I supposedly have a "Message History" folder in my Outlook account, which I don't have now, and I don't recall ever had that. Supposedly I could delete it from there, but I don't have it.

Oh, please note this too. While I have my privacy settings to not keep history at all, my current day chat history can be viewed on Outlook.com /Hotmail website. It is if I go to another sections, say, "Profile", while having the Chat opened that I realized all my conversations are there, stored for months. I don't want that and can't find a way to do it.

So, either this is a big glitch or something so obvious that I'm missing.

This is how to see your message history. Go to live.com/hotmail, and log with your Microsoft account. Activate the chat pane by clicking the happy face smiley icon. Now click on your name and go to your profile. Keep the chat pane open. Click any contact and browse your chat history back. It seems it stores the full past month as I just did this and the history stops exactly on Sep, 3.

How to delete Skype chat history stored on Outlook.com?

Comment: I don't think this should have been migrated. It's about Skype, not really outlook.com.

Answer (score 1):

it is currently not possible to delete the conversation made ​​by Outlook.com chat, manually, but it is deleted by the system after a while. 
I understand it's annoying because I also have private conversations that need removing. 
regards.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled Outlook Chat and hopefully this stops the history being recorded.  I know of no way to delete the history already stored and I have not found where it is stored yet.  Follow this link and you can disable Chat.  Also Johnathon has a program that will revive messenger, I am still using Windows Live Messenger (April 2014)

http://messengergeek.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/how-to-disable-messenger-messaging-in-outlook-com/

Answer (score 0):

My only way to get rid of the private messages is to create another email address and have my "old" emails forwarded to the new email address. This way I still have my emails. I changed the password to my "old" emails. This way it can be stored privately. Hope this helped.

Answer (score -2):

I've installed Skype and used the tools->options->privacy to clean all the conversation history.
It removed all the conversations from Skype and from Outlook.com.

Comment: Nope, it didn't.